# Malloc behavior differs when using gdb

Tags: linux, gdb, malloc

I'm working in a code to test the performance of PCI device using a file descriptor, but I'm struggling with a weird behavior with `malloc`.

Here is the buggy part of the code

```c
    char **writeblock;
    char **readblock;

    writeblock = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*_count);
    if(writeblock == NULL) return;

    readblock = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*_count);
    if(readblock == NULL) return;

    for(int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
    {
        writeblock[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*_blocksize);
        if(writeblock[i] == NULL) return;

        generate_random_buffer(writeblock[i],_blocksize);

        readblock[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*_blocksize);
        if(readblock[i] == NULL) return;
    }
```

And generate_random_buffer:

```c
char *bufseed = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

char *generate_random_buffer(char *_buffer, int _count)
{
    if(_buffer != NULL)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        for(int i = 0; i < _count-1; i++)
        {
            _buffer[i] = bufseed[rand()%62];
        }
        _buffer[_count-1] = '\0'; 
    }

    return _buffer;
}
```

When I run the program normally all the writeblocks presents the exact same content, but when I run with `gdb` placing a breakpoint inside the for loop the code behaves normally (the writeblocks have different content).

My machine runs Xubuntu 20.04 and the machine for testing runs Ubuntu 20.04

**Edit, issue found:**
The `generate_random_buffer` was supposed to generate different random data to `writeblocks` but this was not happening, the problem is with that the function `generate_random_buffer` calls `srand`, leading data to being generated equally every time.

Comment: To me it is not clear what you mean with "all the writeblocks presents the exact same content" or "the writeblocks have different content". How exactly do you check this? Where exactly do you set the breakpoint? I suggest to create a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add this information, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: @Bodo Writting this comment I realized the issue. The `generate_random_buffer` was supposed to generate different random data to `writeblocks` further in the code I was calculating the blocks checksum to see if the checksum match during write and read operations, that is how I found that data was equal in every block. The problem is with the function `generate_random_buffer` calling `srand` on every call this leads to random data being generate equally every time.